# Where to find the header section in SilverStripe?

Tags: silverstripe

I think I'm going crazy I've tried the following:

```
cms/templates (nothing)
framework/templates (nothing)
themes/sunrise/templates (nothing)
themes/sunrise/templates/Page.css (nothing)
```

I'm trying to add extra code between the `<head>` tags. But I still can't find them
Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Page.ss only has this:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div style="position: relative; margin:-320px 0 0 0; width: 100%; min-width: 930px; z-index:-1; border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:8px; border-top-color:#8C2580;">
<div class="clearfix"></div></div>

<div id="content" class="clearfix"><!-- #content start -->

<div id="main" role="main" class="clearfix"><!-- #main start -->


    <section class="post-content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody"><!-- .post-content start -->
        $Content
        $Form
        $PageComments
    </section><!-- .post-content end -->

</div><!-- #main end -->

</div><!-- .content end -->

<div style="position: relative; margin:0 0 0 0; z-index:-1; border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:24px; border-bottom-color:#8C2580">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately this is little to go on for me but I'll give it a shot:

- if you mean things like the  tags,  tags and so on that are inside the head, those come from $MetaTags and the  are just inserted via regex somewhere in the
- if you are searching for the actual  not only what is inside, then it has to be somewhere in a template folder

I am not familiar with the theme you use, maybe it does something like <% include HTMLTop %> or <% incolde Head %> or so to include a template from the Includes folder where the  is in
if it is not there, look in every Page.ss you can find, not only in your theme folder, but also in your mysite/templates if it exists (I personally put all templates inside mysite/templates instead of themes)

---

Another method of finding the template that is being used are the silverstripe source file comments,
if activated, silverstripe will include html comments in the HTML saying what template has been used for exactly what html.
you can activate that like this:

**in ss 2.4**: `SSViewer::set_source_file_comments(true);` in your mysite/_config.php
**in ss 3.0**: i think its broken in 3.0, but you can give the 2.4 version a try
**in ss 3.1:** put the following in your yml config file:

```
SSViewer:
  # display template filenames as comments in the html output
  source_file_comments: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the "sunrise" theme you are using http://sunrise.gpmd.co.uk/ ?

If so, like in most SS themes, you'll find the base for any template in `themes/THEMENAME/templates/Page.ss`.

In this instance the `<head>` starts at line 29. Although, the theme will be used if it has been selected, check your mysite/config (php or yml) and/or setting tab in the CMS.

Comment: I couldn't find anything like that. Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: Which Page.ss is it? Are we talking about the same sunrise theme? Seems like the Page.ss is similar to the one under templates/Layout... while the main one should be under templates/